# Cannot read Excel data with PHPExcel

Tags: html, phpexcel

I want to read an Excel Spreadsheet with PHPExcel. Everything works fine on my local machine with XAMPP. But when I try do upload everythin on my server (domainfactory) I always get this error:

```
    Warning: require_once(Classes/PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: 
    No such file or directory in /kunden/579693_49074/index.php on line 8

    Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
   'Classes/PHPExcel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in 
    /kunden/579693_49074/index.php on line 8
```

I have the excel file and the phpexcel.php on my server.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
    </head>
    <?php
        require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
        $tmpfname = "test.xlsx";
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

        echo "<table>";
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
                echo "</td><tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";    
    ?>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the permissions on the phpexcel.php file. that is probably the issue.

Comment: Doesn't `require_once` require parentheses? Shouldn't it be `require_once("Classes/PHPExcel.php");`? Although if that's the issue, it should be a different error message.

Comment: Apparently require_once doesn't require parentheses. TIL.

Comment: What should the permissions look like?

Comment: should be readible and executable from the user the webserver is running under. then it depends on different parameters: OS, webserver, user or group. You can google for this issue or specifiy your data and try to get help here. As of now it would be just geussing

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick reply. To be honest I'm really new in the php thing. What do you need to know to help me?